# Haskell beginner: Data decl. errors

Tags: haskell

Hello I am trying to write a very simple function in Haskell. However I can't get "ghci" to accept my code.

```
data Field = A1 Int deriving (Show)

data FieldList = FL [Field] | Name String deriving (Show)

t :: Field

t = A1 1

u :: Int -> FieldList

u 0 = FL []

u n = FL [t]:(u (n-1))
```

And the error I get is this:

```
test.hs:9:7:

Couldn't match expected type `FieldList' with actual type `[a0]'

    In the expression: (FL [t]) : (u (n - 1))
    In an equation for `u': u n = (FL [t]) : (u (n - 1))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the last line:

```
u n = FL [t]:(u (n-1))
```

u has the type `Int -> FieldList`. `n` is an `Int`, so `(n - 1)` is also an `Int`. `u (n-1)` would therefor be a `FieldList`.

Function application has a higher precedence than operators, so the above line is equivalent to:

```
u n = (FL [t]) : (u (n - 1) )
```

`FL [t]` is a `FieldList`.

However, `(:)` has the type `a -> [a] -> [a]`. You can see the types don't match, so that is what is causing the problem.

---

What you probably want to do is build up the list of `Field`s (having type `[Field]`), and then turning that into a `FieldList`. Here is some stub code:

```
u :: Int -> FieldList
u n = FL (uHelper n)

uHelper :: Int -> [Field]
uHelper = ... -- write this function
```

Comment: Yep. That's my intention. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

The error says `(FL [t]) : (u (n - 1))` which says that you are trying the List cons function on 
`FL [t]` which is not a list hence you cannot `cons` with it.

I am not sure why you have created a `FieldList` as a new data type which allows a FieldList to be either a List of Field OR a string (which is created using Name constructor) which sort of doesn't make logical sense.

What you can do is make FieldList as:

`type FieldList = [Field]`

And then your function would become:

```
u :: Int -> FieldList
u 0 = []
u n = t : (u (n-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The first argument of list cons `(:)` is an element, not a list, thus: `t : ...` not `[t] : ...`
2. You must unwrap the `FieldList` first to get `[Field]`. Then you can prepend `t` to it.

You want your last line to be

```
u n = case u (n-1) of FL xx -> FL (t:xx)
```

That would of course fail to pattern match if the field list is a `Name` so I would agree with Ankur that there might be a problem with the design...